# What is the write constant

Tags: constants, inno-setup

Is there any constant for

`C:\Users\USER NAME\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\My program` 
Like `{app}`.I tried `{userappdata}` in inno setup

but it is not working.

Comment: What is the difference between {localappdata} vs  {userappdata} & {commonappdata}?and is  {localappdata} use the current user , i mean is it situated in 'username' folder under 'user' folder or 'default'  folder. Please someone explain i am totally confused!!!!

Comment: I've rolled back your last edit. Please do not change the questions that way. You are making a moving target from them. You've asked for something and it's been closed as a duplicate. Case closed. If you have a new question, ask the new one. Thank you!

Comment: @ TLama I know i was wrong but i was compelled to do that. Because ask question showing this notification "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more. "Sorry!!!!!!!