# Check System Architecture in Inno Setup

Tags: crystal-reports, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am using `Inno Setup` to create a BootStrapper for My `.NET` developed project.

While using `PascalScript`, I am facing some problems. But before that, here is the Script I am using to create the `BootStrapper`

```
#define MyAppName "<ProductName>"
#define MyAppVersion "<ProductVersion>"
#define MyAppPublisher "<Company Name>"
#define MyAppURL "<URL>"
#define MyAppExeName "<AppName>.exe"
#define MyAppCopyright "Copyright@2015"
#define MyContact "<Contact No>"

[Setup]
AppId={{69A884D3-671F-4DFB-9E23-F6FA35BD6264}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableDirPage=yes
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
LicenseFile=<License File Path>
OutputDir=<Output Directory Path>
OutputBaseFilename=<Output File Name>
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
SetupIconFile=<Icon File Path>
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
AppCopyright={#MyAppCopyright}
AppContact={#MyContact}
VersionInfoVersion=1.5
VersionInfoCompany=<Company Name>
VersionInfoProductName=<Product Name>
VersionInfoProductVersion=<Product Version>

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
Name: "quicklaunchicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateQuickLaunchIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6.1

[Files]
Source: "<Path>\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall; Permissions: admins-full; Check: Framework45IsNotInstalled
Source: "<Path>\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_13.msi"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall 32bit; Permissions: admins-full;
Source: "<Path>\CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_14.msi"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: 64bit deleteafterinstall; Permissions: admins-full; Check: IsWin64
Source: "<Path>\SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall 32bit; Permissions: admins-full
Source: "<Path>\SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: 64bit deleteafterinstall; Permissions: admins-full; Check: IsWin64

Source: "<Path>\<Product>.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "<Path>\File1.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Run]
Filename: {tmp}\NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe; Parameters: "/q /norestart"; Check: Framework45IsNotInstalled; StatusMsg: Microsoft Framework 4.0 is being installed. This process might take some time. Please wait.....

Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_13.msi"; StatusMsg: Crystal Reports Runtime is being installed. Please wait....;

Filename: {tmp}\SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.exe; StatusMsg: Microsoft SQL Compact 4.0 is being installed. Please wait.....

[Code]
function Framework45IsNotInstalled(): Boolean;
var
  regresult: Cardinal;
begin
  RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, 'Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', 'Install', regresult);
  if (regresult = 0) then 
  begin
    Result := True;
  end
  else
  begin
  Result := False;
  end;
end;

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Now I have three problems regarding this issue :

1. **How to check if the system architecture is 32Bit or 64Bit and execute the respective file accordingly ?**

e.g. As mentioned in the script, I have attached Two files for `Crystal Reports`, Now while executing setup, setup should detect the System Architecture and Run the respective file. I tried to solve this using [This Link here on StackOverdlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203891/how-to-check-64-32-bit-in-inno-setup) but didn't quite understand it.

2. **Check if the Prerequisite is already installed on System or not**

e.g. To check if the `.NET Framework` already installed on machine, I got the script mentioned above and its working fine. How to do that for `Crystal Report` or `SQL Compact` ?

I tried this Script for `Crystal Report` but it's not working.

```
[Code]
function CheckForCrystalReports: Boolean;
var
  regresul: Cardinal;
begin
  RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Suite XI 4.0\Installer\CRV','Install',regresul);
  if(regresul = 0) then
  begin
  Result := True;
  end 
  else
  begin
  Result := False;
  end; 
end;
```

3. **Run executable in Silent Mode**

e.g. In above script, I am using `Parameters: "/q /norestart";` to run the setup in Silent mode and its working. But how to do that for `*.msi` file ? I tried some parameters but they are not working.

Comment: You cannot ask three distinct questions in a single post.

Comment: Anyway for the first question, see [Inno-setup 32bit and 64bit in one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4833831/850848).

Comment: [msi command line switches](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and [msdn source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : Sorry for Big question and Thanks for the link. It worked.

Comment: @RobeN : Thanks for the link. I tried that already but the parameter `/q` or `/qn` isn't working. While execution, it prompts error message as `Parameters not supported`.

Comment: @Mahadev is this installer available on network? If yes, I could check if it supports parameters.

Comment: @RobeN : No but `CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_13.msi` can be downloaded to check the parameters to use with.

Comment: I have tried `msiexec /passive /i "C:\CRRuntimeTest\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_13.msi"` and it worked as intended. Show us you `Code` as probably there is kind of problem. Exaple `[Run] Filename: "{tmp}\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_13.msi"; Parameters: "/passive"; Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated skipifdoesntexist; StatusMsg: "Installing CRRuntime..."`

Comment: @RobeN : Here is the Code from above question. `[Run]`
`Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{tmp}\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_13.msi"; StatusMsg: Crystal Reports Runtime is being installed. Please wait....;
`
May be I just don't know how to use it in above context and I tried `/passive` but is isn't working in above line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution with `ShellExec`:

```
[Run] 
Filename: "{tmp}\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_13.msi"; Parameters: "/passive";
 Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated skipifdoesntexist;
 StatusMsg: "Crystal Reports Runtime is being installed. Please wait...";
```

If you want to call via `MSIEXEC`:

```
[Run] 
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/passive /i ""{tmp}\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_13.msi"""; 
 Flags: waituntilterminated skipifdoesntexist; 
 StatusMsg: "Crystal Reports Runtime is being installed. Please wait...";
```

*P.S. In your code snippet from Comment there were quotations missing for `Parameters`. You should Open and Close Parameters with `"` then if you need to use quotation in the parameters line you have to use it Doubled. `""`*

---

For `SQL Compact` you may use following code:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Temp\SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; 
 Flags: nocompression deleteafterinstall uninsremovereadonly  
Source: "C:\Temp\SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; 
 Flags: nocompression deleteafterinstall uninsremovereadonly  

[Run] 
Filename: "{tmp}\SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.exe"; Parameters: "/qn /i";  
 Flags: waituntilterminated skipifdoesntexist; 
 StatusMsg: SQL Compact 4.0 x64 is being installed. Please wait...; 
 Check: (IsWin64) and (not IsSQLCompact40Installed); 
Filename: "{tmp}\SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.exe"; Parameters: "/qn /i";  
 Flags: waituntilterminated skipifdoesntexist; 
 StatusMsg: SQL Compact 4.0 x86 is being installed. Please wait...; 
 Check: (not IsWin64) and (not IsSQLCompact40Installed); 

[Code]
function IsSQLCompact40Installed(): Boolean;
var
  InstallDirString : String;
begin
  result := false;
  if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0',
   'InstallDir', InstallDirString) then begin
    if FileExists(InstallDirString + '\sqlcecompact40.dll') then
       result := true;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm. Can you help me with my other mentioned problems ?

Comment: I have a Question No. 2 still pending. :)

Comment: Export and attach registry branch for `HKLM` `\SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects`. You would also have to specify which version of SQL Compact you want to check - 3.5, 4.0? x86, x64?

Comment: @Mahadev I have updated the answer with sample check for SQL Compact

Comment: @RobenN : Thank you very much but I have already solved it for SQL Compact. But thank you for `IsSQLCompact40Installed()`. If possible, just let me know any similar registry entry for crystal report.

Comment: @Mahadev For `CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_13.msi` you can use: `RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Enterprise\InstallRoot', 'Path', CristalPath)` and there you can check if specific `FileExists` in `win32_x86` subfolder.

Comment: @RobenN : Thanks. That'll definitely help. :)